# code is randomly not working (trying to make a real time scanner to detect incoming files and scan them)

Tags: python, loops, file, hash

So I am trying to make a real time scanner at the moment which basically just doesn't work and I don't know why, could someone help me and improve/correct my code or explain  why it is not working?

I have absolutely no idea why it is not working and I tried everything but I also don't get any erros. I think it is because of the seconds thing I tried to do.

That is my code:

```
import time
import os
import hashlib
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

cwd = os.getcwd()

def download_wait(path_to_downloads):
    seconds = 0
    dl_wait = True
    file_endings = [".opdownload", ".crdownload", ".partial", ".part", ".!ut"]
    while dl_wait and seconds < 20:
        time.sleep(1)
        dl_wait = False
        for fname in os.listdir(path_to_downloads):
            for file_ending_check in file_endings:
                if fname.endswith(file_ending_check):
                    dl_wait = True
                    for file in os.listdir(path_to_downloads):
                        if file.endswith(file_ending_check):
                            unfinished_file = os.path.join(path_to_downloads, file)
                            hash1 = hashlib.md5()
                            hash1.update(unfinished_file)
                            hash1.digest()
                            all_files = [f for f in listdir(path_to_downloads) if isfile(join(path_to_downloads, f))]
                            for file_check in all_files:
                                hash2 = hashlib.md5()
                                hash1.update(file_check)
                                hash2.digest()
                                ### code to upload the file to virustotal will be here
        seconds += 1

download_wait(cwd)
```

I expected it to keep checking for new files in the Downloads folder, waiting for the download to be finished and then do something with the new file, but I don't even know how to get the new name of the file when it is finished.

Comment: If you want to do what you're doing it's probably best to use [`watchdog`](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/), here are [le docs](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/)

Comment: 8 levels of indentation...  impressive.